# How to force setup.py to unpack module files?

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, setup.py

Python version: **2.7.12**

I created my own Python module. Here is a simple structure which I want to **precisely reproduce** inside one of directory pointed by `sys.path`:

```
|-- setup.py
|-- mynamespace/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- mymodule/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- mymodule.py
```

Because it is simple project, `setup.py` contains the list:

```
py_modules = ['mynamespace.mymodule.mymodule']
```

I can install the module typing:

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

I noticed that *setuptools* printed out the path during the installation process. When I go there I can see `mymodule-*.egg` file. Thanks to him I'm able to load my module from any localization. But the `.egg` file is something like an archive (when I change its extension, for example into `.zip`, I can unpack files and find the structure of directories). I know that file brings a cross-platform compatibility solution.

I think that possessing unpacked directories is better solution. In the near future I would publish another modules inside `mynamespace` directory:

```
>>> from mynamespace import mymodule
>>> from mynamespace import mymodule1
>>> from mynamespace import mymodule2
...
```

I know `bash` and I can write own installation script. I can even use Python to do this but I think the more professional approach is to use dedicated tools.

Comment: Actually the `.egg` file is a directory which contains your package. So if you want to access the installed modules you can just navigate to `/.../site-packages/mymodule-*.egg`. It should contain your package as `mymodule` and installation information as `EGG-INFO`.

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate [namespace packaging](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0382/).  I think that it will meet your needs.  The documentation at the [Python Packaging Authority](https://www.pypa.io/) explains the various methods of deploying modules, packages, and namespace packages.

Python package management is pretty complex and very flexible so I would definitely not recommend rolling your own installation mechanism.  I would also recommend the simplest approach that works.  Personally, I have used [namespace packages](https://github.com/sprockets/sprockets.http), [individual modules](https://github.com/gmr/tdns), and [packages](https://github.com/dave-shawley/ietfparse).  I've come to the conclusion that using simple flat packages is the most reliable mechanism.  They also follow the "Simple is better than complex" and "Flat is better than nested" principles from the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).